# Are Arcanines with the worst movesets good against strong fire-type pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

The worst moveset for Arcanine is Bite/Bulldoze. Are they able to defeat fire-type Pokémon around its current CP?

Comment: Pretty much anything can beat anything if you're good at dodging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if Bulldoze is a good move against fire types, then ground types are super effective against fire types.

That doesn't matter much though since Bite has a higher DPS, so it isn't really too effective to use Bulldoze all that much anyway.

Regardless, there are much easier ways to take down a fire type such as using a water pokemon with STAB, preferably one with Water Gun/Hydro Pump.

- If the arcanine is the attacker, then there are better ways to take down a fire type
- If it is the defender, it doesn't matter anyway since the attacker can attack faster and can choose an opponent that would be stronger.